# Show events in agendaWeek view only

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is there a way to show certain events in agendaWeek only in fullcalendar. Is there a way to distinguish those events as agendaWeek events?
Can anyone help?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
Firstof all you have to figure out which events you want to show in agendaWeek view. After that you can add element in event object as agendaWeek identification.

Like

```
events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2010-01-01',
            event_type: 'month'
        },
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2010-01-02',
            event_type: 'agendaWeek'
        },
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2010-01-01',
            event_type: 'agendaWeek'
        }
        // more events here
    ],
```

Then you can filter it while rendering.

```
eventRender: function( event, element, view ) { 
    if (view.name == 'agendaWeek' && event.event_type != 'agendaWeek') {
        element.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!